# Accessing dictionary of functions from another python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a sample code the recreates an error I am getting in my project. Maybe I am missing something, but cannot seem to understand what I am doing wrong here.

I have two files:

my_functions.py which contains the following code

```
func_dict = {'f1': func1, 'f2': func2}

def func1():
    print('func1')

def func2():
    print('func2')
```

and a main.py that tries to load function dictionary and run each function:

```
from my_functions import func_dict

func_dict['f1']()
func_dict['f2']()
```

When I run main.py, I get an error on `from my_functions import func_dict` which says:

> Exception has occurred: NameError name 'func1' is not defined

How do I fix this? If I am doing something wrong, then please do correct me. I am basically trying to load a dictionary that relates easier to remember keys to more complicated function names in the module.

Comment: because when you create your dictionary, those functions aren't defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please place the 2 functions over the dictionary definition as the following and try again. That should fix the NameError -

```
def func1():
    print('func1')

def func2():
    print('func2')

func_dict = {'f1': func1, 'f2': func2}
```

Comment: Thanks man! That was the issue, could not believe how I overlooked it.